# Adding Elements of an Array (sum of rows and columns)

Tags: java, arrays, sum, row

I'm looking for a way to add up the elements of the rows of an array and get that sum. I have to get the column's sum as well.
The array looks something like this:

```
     {{45.24, 54.67, 32.55, 25.61},
      {65.29, 49.75, 32.08, 26.11},
      {25.24, 54.33, 34.55, 28.16}};
```

For example, I would add 45.24, 65.29, and 25.24 to get the sum of that part of the columns. I would then have to add the other 3 columns up as well.
Same goes for the rows.
I keep getting errors concerning the variable types. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what language you want it in?

Comment: If anyone is on here confused, please just tell me how to find the answer. You don't need to give me the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The logic Would be `--->`

```
for(i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
 for(j=0; j<rows; j++)
 {
  sum+=arr[j][i];
 }
}
```

Opposite for Columns

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `nxn` matrix. The idea is to identify the *pattern*.

**Row values**

`i j`
`0 0`
`0 1`
`0 2`

**Column values**

`i j`
`0 0`
`1 0`
`2 0`

The position of `i` and `j` values is reversed.

Let's assume we have an array `a[][]`. The logic would be:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

        row += a[i][j];
        col += a[j][i];
    }
    System.out.println("row" + i + " = " + row);
    System.out.println("col" + i + " = " + col);
}
```

I assumed you wanted the sum of each row and column separately. You can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the type of numbers your array will handle, if I use float numbers I can have some code like the class bellow to do the type of operations you are asked for.  You can also add some decimal formatting.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        float myarray[][]=  { 
            {45.24f, 54.67f, 32.55f, 25.61f},
            {65.29f, 49.75f, 32.08f, 26.11f},
            {25.24f, 54.33f, 34.55f, 28.16f}
        };

        float row[] = new float[3];
        float column[] = new float[4];

        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {

            float rowvalue = 0f;

            for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(myarray[i][j]+" ");
                rowvalue+=myarray[i][j];
            }
            row[i]=rowvalue;

            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {

            float colvalue = 0f;

            for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(myarray[j][i]+" ");
                colvalue+=myarray[j][i];
            }
            column[i]=colvalue;

            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("Rows answer:");
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(row[i]);    
        }
        System.out.println("Columns answer:");
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(column[i]);    
        }

    }
}
```